# Unable to exclude IPv4 addresses using regex in grep

Tags: grep

I used a regex to grep and output only IPv4 addresses from the file content.

But when I try to use the same regex to exclude all IPv4 addresses, it just does not work.

File content:

```
# cat IPs
172.16.1.125
172.16.1.4
172.16.1.143
172.16.1.140
172.16.1.77
/dev/nvme101
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb2
172.16.1.60
172.16.1.146
172.16.1.5
172.16.1.51
172.16.1.99
172.16.1.10
172.16.1.189
```

To grep only IPv4 addresses:

```
# grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" IPs
172.16.1.125
172.16.1.4
172.16.1.143
172.16.1.140
172.16.1.77
172.16.1.60
172.16.1.146
172.16.1.5
172.16.1.51
172.16.1.99
172.16.1.10
172.16.1.189
```

When I try to exclude the IPv4 addresses using the same regex:

```
# grep -voE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" IPs
#
```

No output at all.

I was expecting the following output:

```
/dev/nvme101
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb2
```

Comment: Did you try to omit the `-o` parameter? `grep -vE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" IPs`

Comment: oh yeh, flag `o` was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `-o`. The `-o` flag says to only show what was matched rather than the entire line. That doesn't make sense when using `-v` for lines that do NOT match.

In [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com), if you try to use `-o` and `-v` together, it throws an error.